# Trouble in paradise with namespaces. Class is accessible in methods but not on extends

Tags: php, inheritance, namespaces

I have trouble understanding the import behavior. Let me explain, I have a class B outside of any namespace (for some reason I have double autoload, a proprietary one, and the classic PSR-4, I guess this can have something to do with my issue, I'm ready to gather more information on this tidbit if necessary). In this class I import a class A from a namespace, and it turns out when in a method of my children class I can use the A class to instantiate an object, but when I try to tell class B to extend class A it says the FQN is not found.

```
<?php
use \App\Services\AbstractController as BaseController;

class BarController extends BaseController
{

    public function test() {
        $foo = new BaseController();
    }
}
```

There I would have an error on the "class BarController extends BaseController" line saying BaseController can't be found, but if I delete the extends part, the test method will run smoothly with its instantiation (I did try to manipulate the object, it sure works well).

so I guess my question is, is there any difference on the treatment of a class to extend vs. using it to instantiate an object.

Thanks in advance for your thoughts, and I'm ready to answer any additional question.

Comment: It seems to be a problem with your autoload, because your code is fully functional: https://3v4l.org/FHcH3 
The main point about autoload is that even you don't use the keyword `as`, internally, it does like that `use \App\Services\AbstractController as AbstractController`

Comment: Hi Gabriel thanks for your input. I did manage to deal with the issue. The controller class was instantiated inside the proprietary autoloader but the method was called later on the process. I switched both autoloader order (ie. first psr-4 then proprietary one) in the init and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

I did manage to deal with the issue. The controller class was instantiated inside the proprietary autoloader but the method was called later on the process. I switched both autoloader order (ie. first psr-4 then proprietary one) in the init and it works well.